# Which are the factionless quests in New Vegas that reward with enough experience points to reach a high level?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm finally running for and independent Vegas in Fallout: New Vegas and I want to do as many quests as I can in order to level up to level 25 and then play the DLC's. Since I'm roleplaying independent and I don't want to work for House, the NCR or the Legion, I want to know which are the non-faction quests available.

From previous gameplays I already know some town-related quests such as Goodsprings, Novac, Freeside, North Vegas Square, the Families, the Crinsom Caravan, BoS, the Kings...those sort of quests are the ones I want to play in order to level up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in a sense you can remain neutral even doing NCR, Legion or House quests, it's just that at one point House, the NCR and The Legion will assume which side you have chosen after a certain question with one of those factions, after all you have to help the Legion in order to get into the bunker to use the Platinum Chip.

Comment: For the independent ending, just side with Yes Man at the end.  There is actually an in-game warning along the lines of "If you proceed with this quest, other factions will no longer like you"  At that point, just stick with Yes Man's quest and you get an independent New Vegas.

Comment: @Nelson I know about Yes-Man and the warning stuff, what I need is something like the answer provided by FoxMcCloud in his answer

Answer (score 3):

These 4 give 1000+ XP and are totally independent like you asked.

[A valuable lesson 1600 XP](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/A_Valuable_Lesson)

[Come fly with me 1000 XP](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Come_Fly_With_Me)

[Crazy crazy crazy 1000 XP](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy,_Crazy,_Crazy)

[GI Blues 500-1500 XP](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/G.I._Blues)

A list of all Fallout New Vegas quests can be found [HERE](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_quests) and this link includes rewards and walkthroughs.